# Android Studio is not selecting text properly

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, android-settings

I guess accidentally pressing a key or a combination changed a setting in Android Studio after which android studio is acting weird and won't let me select code properly.

Look at following image.

[image]

I have checked Android Studio setting and couldn't find anything related to it.

P.S I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 17):

In 3.3.1 column select mode is under the Edit menu

Answer (score 13):

To enter/exit column selection mode, press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd>.

After deactivating, you can still do column selection with using <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>left click drag</kbd>.

Comment: what are the keys for mac?

Answer (score 0):

In mac, to switch the Column Selection mode you can press shift + cmd + 8

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).